# SQL LIKE exclusive substring

Tags: sql, database, sql-like

I have in a column in SQL a field that concatenates products a given user has reviewed. It's stored in the form "SKU1,SKU2,SKU3,...". An example string would be "1,2,4,6,13,15,16".

I want to view all rows containing '6' in this column. I'd use LIKE, but then it gets 16, 26, 36, etc as well.

```
SELECT rows
    FROM table
    WHERE column LIKE '%6%'
    -- will get 6, 16, 26, ...

SELECT rows
    FROM table
    WHERE column LIKE '%6%'
    AND column NOT LIKE '%16%'
    AND column NOT LIKE '%26%'
        ...
        ...
    -- will get 6, but only in rows without 16, 26, ...
```

I want to get all rows containing "6", but not rows containing "16", "26", etc without also having "6". I do want rows containing "6" alone, "6" AND "16", "26", etc but not rows with "6" OR "16", "26", etc. What am I missing?

Comment: try this like '%,6%'

Comment: Never ever **EVER** put CSV data into a column.

Comment: I'll take "6" alone, "6" AND "60", but not "6" OR "60".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a fundamental mistake in the design of the database.  The correct solution is to replace the column `column` with a separate table.  This table will have two columns, the user ID and the product ID and will have one separate row for each product a user has reviewed.  It then becomes quite easy to get the information you need.

Failing that, you will have to write a complex WHERE clause with three parts to test for "%, 6, %" (with the spaces before and after or "6, % " or "%, 6".  This will be slow to execute as the database gets larger, is not indexible, is not JOINable, and cannot be subject to referential integrity.  If you are inconsistent in your use of spaces when storing data the search expression becomes more complex.

Note that some SQL databases (you didn't say which you're using) have substring functions to make this kind of search slightly easier but even in those database the design is still a terrible violation of relational principles and first normal form and should be refactored at your earliest possible opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

This where condition would give you the result you're looking for.

```
mycolumn like "%,6,%" or mycolumn like '6,%' or mycolumn like '%,6'
```

Here' I'm using the fact that commas would appear on either side of 6, except if the 6 comes at the start or end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lousy database design, but you can do what you want with:

```
WHERE ','||column||',' LIKE '%,6,%'
```

What you really want is a junction table, with one column for the SKU and another column that identifies what the row belongs to.

You see, SQL has this great mechanism for storing lists of things.  It is called a *table*, not a comma delimited list.  Some significant problems with storing ids in columns:

- You cannot check referential integrity.
- Removing elements is a pain.
- Looking up associated values is a pain.
- The engine cannot take advantage of an index for simple searches, such as the one you ask about.
- Storing integers as strings is just a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

If your database allows for it, you should check, whether something along, e.g.,
`CHARINDEX (',6,', CONCAT(',', yourColumn, ',')) > 0`
for SQL Server or
`WHERE INSTR(',' || yourColumn || ',', ',6,') > 0`
for Oracle does perform better than a `LIKE` based solution. (Once, you are at it, verify the effect of an index on the column in question for the alternative queries.)

But only, of course, if changing your database design -as rightfully suggested above-, is no option.